# Android block screen when opening dialog or second dialog instance

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

I have an extended DialogFragment which is opening from current Fragment.
Recently I've found that it's possible to click on element which causes dialog opening two times in short time period and it will force to open two dialogs one above another. It's unexpected behavior for my app. I would like to make possible open only one dialog instance. What I'm doing wrong?

Below is my code for dialog opening.

```
public boolean onActionItemSelected(int menuId) {

    switch (menuId) {
        case R.id.action_change_passcode:
            pinChangeFlag = true;
            AbstractPinDialog pinChangeFirstDialog = new StandardPinDialog(this);
            pinChangeFirstDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), StandardPinDialog.class.getName());
            return true;
            //... other cases
    } 
}
```

Comment: Id `action_change_passcode` a `Button`?

Comment: @Apoorv it's a code of item from ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to set a global boolean tag like

```
isDialogVisible=false;
```

when you show the dialog, set its value as true. before showing that dialog box check

```
if(! isDialogVisible){
    dialog.show();
}
```

so only one dialog box will appear.

Or the second way is to check if view of the dialog box has been created or not, then use similar logic to not show the second dialog.

Comment: yes, this solution is clear, thanks. maybe here are some predefined triggers for that?

Comment: And how will you check if dialog was closed by user? By implementing dismiss listener in targety DialogFragment?

Comment: the place where you dismiss the dialog, just set isDialogVisible=false again. isDialogVisible is a global variable